# Implementing a flambo mapValues function in clojure

Tags: clojure, apache-spark, rdd, flambo

I have a clojure function that uses the flambo v0.60 functions api to do some analysis on a sample data set. I noticed that when I use a `(get rdd 2)` instead of getting the second element in the rdd collection, its getting the second character of the first element of the rdd collection. My assumption is clojure is treating each row of the rdd collection as a whole string and not a vector for me to be able to get the second element in the collection. I'm thinking of using the map-values function to convert the mapped values into a vector for which I can get the second element, I tried this:

```
(defn split-on-tab-transformation [xctx input]
 (assoc xctx :rdd (-> (:rdd xctx)
                   (spark/map (spark/fn [row] (s/split row #"\t")))
                   (spark/map-values vec))))
```

Unfortunately I got an error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: mapValues for class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD...`

This is code returns the first collection in the rdd:
(assuming I removed the `(spark/map-values vec)` in the above function

```
(defn get-distinct-column-val
 "input = {:col val}"
  [ xctx input ]
  (let [rdds (-> (:rdd xctx)
           (f/map (f/fn [row] row))
           f/first)]
(clojure.pprint/pprint rdds)))
```

Output:

```
[2.00000 770127      200939.000000   \t6094\tBENTONVILLE, AR DPS\t22.500000\t5.000000\t2.500000\t5.000000\t0.000000\t0.000000\t0.000000\t0.000000\t0.000000\t1\tStore Tab\t0.000000\t4.50\t3.83\t5.00\t0.000000\t0.000000\t0.000000\t0.000000\t19.150000]
```

if I try to get the second element `770127`

```
(defn get-distinct-column-val
 "input = {:col val}"
  [ xctx input ]
  (let [rdds (-> (:rdd xctx)
           (f/map (f/fn [row] row))
           f/first)]
   (clojure.pprint/pprint (get rdds 1)))
```

I get :

```
[\.]
```

[Flambo documentation for map-values](http://yieldbot.github.io/flambo/codox/flambo.api.html#var-map-values)

I'm new to clojure and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: @noisesmith  can you please help me out with this challenge

Comment: @cbbetz can you help me out with this flambo and clojure problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `map-values` (or `mapValues` in Spark API) is a valid transformation only on a PairRDD (for example something like this `[:foo [1 2 3]]`. RDDs with values like this can be interpreted as some some sort of maps where the first element is a key and the second is a value.

If you have RDD like this `mapValues` transforms the values without changing the key. In this case you should use a second map, although it seem obsolete since `clojure.string/split` already returns a vector.

A simple example of using `map-values`:

```lisp
(let [pairs [(ft/tuple :foo 1) (ft/tuple :bar 2)]
      rdd (f/parallelize-pairs sc pairs) ;; Note parallelize-pairs -> PairRDD
      result (-> rdd       
          (f/map-values inc) ;; Map values
          (f/collect))]
  (assert (= result [(ft/tuple :foo 2) (ft/tuple :bar 3)])))
```

From your description it looks like you're using an input RDD instead of the one returned from `split-on-tab-transformation`. If I had to guess you're trying to use original `xctx`, not the one returned from `split-on-tab-transformation`. Since Clojure `maps` are immutable `assoc` doesn't change a passed argument and `get-distinct-column-val` receives `RDD[String]` not `RDD[Array[String]]`

Based on a naming convention I assume you want to get distinct values for a single position in a array. I removed unused parts of your code for clarity. First lets create dummy data:

```lisp
(spit "data.txt"
      (str "Mazda RX4\t21\t6\t160\n"
           "Mazda RX4 Wag\t21\t6\t160\n"
           "Datsun 710\t22.8\t4\t108\n"))
```

add rewritten versions of your functions

```lisp
(defn split-on-tab-transformation [xctx]
   (assoc xctx :rdd (-> (:rdd xctx)
                        (f/map #(clojure.string/split % #"\t")))))

(defn get-distinct-column-val
  [xctx col]
    (-> (:rdd xctx)
      (f/map #(get % col))
        (f/distinct)))
```

and result

```lisp
(assert
 (= #{"Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Mazda RX4"}
    (-> {:sc sc :rdd (f/text-file sc "data.txt")}
      (split-on-tab-transformation)
      (get-distinct-column-val 0)
      (f/collect)
      (set))))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can be updating the`:rdd` in the `xctx` map with the `latest` transformation on the RDD without using the `assoc`, Or is the `assoc` going to update the `:rdd` key with the value from the transformation. And you actually got your assumptions right for the problem. I really appreciate the help.. I just want to be clear with the `assoc` clojure function.

Comment: Clojure data structures are immutable so there is really no such a thing as an update. You always get a new data structure. You could make `xctx` an [`atom`](http://clojure.org/atoms) and use `swap!` but I doubt it is a good idea. Capturing an output like above is much cleaner solution and ensures referential transparency. BTW If you like the answer I won't mind an upvote :-)

Comment: One more question, from the example, will the  `split-on-tab-transformation` change the value of the `:rdd` key in `xctx`, such that when `get-distinct-column-val` gets to use  `:rdd` key in xctx, its actually working with the new value from the `split-on-tab-transformation` and not its former value?  Thanks

Comment: Exactly. `split-on-tab-transformation` returns result of `assoc` which is a new map with `:rdd` equal to `(-> (:rdd xctx) .... )` and it is passed to `get-distinct-column-val`.

Comment: Thanks @zero323 what happened is I inherited a code base to work on and found out that some of my functions were not working on the target columns.. also the functions are not arranged in a thread, which obviously would have made it better, The `xctx` is defined somewhere else and i really doubt if they declared it as an `atom`. I will suggest we use an atom to move data around in the application especially when the data is being modified for different functions to be able to use that particular data for evaluations. Would you agree to this suggestion or kindly advice the way to go. Thanks

Comment: Working with a mutable state adds a whole new level of complexity to your code. So in my opinion fundamental question is if it is really worth it. Generally speaking I would say it is not. I am not sure why you need `xctx` in the first place. I don't have experience with `flambo` (first time today) and  with Clojure for that matter (unless you count some toy projects) but when it comes to Spark it feels pretty natural to simply pass RDDs around. Since RDD with transformations is just a recipe it is lightweight approach and makes reasoning about the program much easier.